# Android alignment horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, button, alignment

hi i need to knw how to align button , text view and other things in ,

example when i add a button into the edge of the bottom of the screen bt when i turn screen into horizontal  i want it to be in the same place.that means i want to be it in the edge of the bottom of the screen with  same bottom padding.

How i could do this

this is the  button code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_enter"
       android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textColor="#000" 
        android:fontFamily="serif"

     />
```

i need when its turn into horizontal that button to be in the exact same place

thanks you 
regards pran

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Button is inside a RelativeLayout,

Use these properties for button:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

If Button is inside a LinearLayout,

Use layout_gravity for button:

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

add this for your button if it s in relative layout

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

otherwise

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: ... if its in a RelativeLayout